# How to get the selection node and project name and path from every view in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP Plugin view and I need to take the selected project in the views Project Explorer and Navigator from Eclipse. I'm currently doing this by recognizing them using their ID. But is there a posibility to eliminate the hard coded ID ?

(For example, every view in Eclipse that would contain project display could trigger my view when the selection is changed)

Current code:

```
    IProject project;
        ISelectionService  selectionService=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");

if(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            Object element = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();

            if (element instanceof IResource) {
                project= ((IResource)element).getProject();

            }
            else if (element instanceof IPackageFragmentRoot) {
                IJavaProject jProject = ((IPackageFragmentRoot)element).getJavaProject();
                project = jProject.getProject();
            }
            else if (element instanceof IJavaElement) {
                IJavaProject jProject= ((IJavaElement)element).getJavaProject();
                project = jProject.getProject();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about all the views open on a page using:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewReference [] viewRefs = page.getViewReferences();

for (IViewReference viewRef : viewRefs)
 {
   String id = viewRef.getId();

   ... use id in getSelection
 }
```

Comment: And how to trigger the view when the selection changes, for example ? Without running a thread or timer....

Comment: If you want to see selections changing in a view you will have to use `ISelectionService.addSelectionListener`. To see view parts opening and closing use `IWorkbenchPage.addPartListener`.